# Select from ReportEvent returns only one row

Tags: event-monitoring

Executing this query in Developer Console returns only one row whereas in Workbench it returns hundreds of rows

```
SELECT Id, Name, ColumnHeaders, Operation, QueriedEntities, RowsProcessed 
  FROM ReportEvent
```

How can this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that ReportEvent rows all have the same "no ID" ID = `000000000000000AAA` and Developer Console merges them altogether into one result row.

Remove the ID from the query and it displays correctly in Developer Console:

```
SELECT Name, ColumnHeaders, Operation, QueriedEntities, RowsProcessed from ReportEvent
```

Related - [Query on EventBusSubscriber returns only 1 row](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234667/developer-console-query-on-eventbussubscriber-returns-only-1-row)